# Gradle test dependency on main sourceset

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm using gradle to build my spring-boot project with the **java** plugin and I need to explicitly describe that the Test Source Sets depends on the Main source set in order for Intellij to see the main classes. Shouldn't this be implied?

```
dependencies {
    testCompile sourceSets.main.output
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Can you build the project by Gradle from command line? Provide a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: It does. When you browse to a test  using Intellij, can it see classes from the main app?

Comment: I'm inclined to think it's something with gradle. This doesn't happen with 4.10, only with 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue with spring boot 2.4.

The dependencies could be removed, after upgrading to spring boot 2.5.

Tested with spring boot sample project:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/